# MATLAB overlaps() with only two polyshap objects

Tags: matlab, plot, polygon, matlab-figure

In my problem, I have a car and multiple obstacle polyshaps objects, and I want to determine if the car is overlapping only one of the objects. I found out that the `overlaps` command is very expensive, perhaps because it also checks if the obstacles overlap each other (a check that I don't need!)

if I do something like `table = overlaps([car obstacle3 obstacle2])` I will get a matrix that shows me all of the possible overlaps with those 3 shapes.

**I'm looking for a simple solution that will give me a true or false value - if the car object overlaps one of the obstacles (or more).**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So basically you don't need the full output of `overlaps()`, rather it can terminate as soon as a matching point is found?

Comment: Yes. Is there such a command for that?